# jquery-handsontable: passing a function to colWidth option

Tags: jquery, html, css, handsontable

### Background

In [this](http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html) [handsontable](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable) tutorial, this line appears:

```
colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80], //can also be a number or a function
```

### The ask...

Does anyone know (and have an example for) the use of the `colWidths` option when passing it a *function*?

- Does this allow custom rendering of dynamic table resizing?
- When is this function called?
- What is the prototype?
- Why is this functionality included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a constructor option.
If a function is possible, then:

```
colWidths: function(){ return [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]; },
```